# How can I search and return an object by going through a queue in Java?

Tags: java, list, queue

I'm trying to find an item (an object) of a node in my queue, in which it goes through it until it finds that and then returns it, for example:

I have a "Skills" object which will manage the skill and years of experience (with its respective get and set)

```
public class Skills {
    private String skill;
    private int years;

    public Skills(String skill, int years) {
        this.skill = skill;
        this.years = years;
    }
}
```

I have a "Person" object which will manage the name and the list of skills of the person

```
public class Person {
    private QueueList<Skills> skillsList;

    // Adds a skill to a person.
    public void AddSkill(String skill, int years) {
        skillsList.add(new Skills(skill, years));
    }
}
```

I have a generic "Node" (with its respective get and set)

```
public class Node<E> {
    private E item;
    private Node nextNode;

    public Node(E item) {
        this.item = item;
        this.nextNode = null;
    }
}
```

And finally I have a manual generic "QueueList" with its respective methods (like add)

```
public class QueueList<E> {
    private Node<E> firstNode;
    private Node<E> lastNode;

    public QueueList() {
        this.firstNode = null;
        this.lastNode = null;
    }

    public void add(E item) {
        if (lastNode == null) {
            lastNode = new Node<>(item);
            firstNode = lastNode;
        } else {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(item);
            lastNode.setNextNode(newNode);
            lastNode = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create a queue list of people in the main class

```
Person p = new Person("Mark");

p.AddSkill("Programming", 0);
p.AddSkill("Drawing", 0);
p.AddSkill("Dancing", 1);
p.AddSkill("Cooking", 5);
```

I want to do a method `public Skills getSkills()` in my "QueueList" class that goes through the list of skills of the person, and returns each object that is in each node, so I can go through it with a foreach from the "Person" class to return a list of skills without years of experience

```
// Returns a list of skills without years of experience (0 years)
public ArrayList PeopleWithoutExperience(){
    ArrayList<Skills> noSkillsList = new ArrayList();
    // TODO
    return noSkillsList;
}
```

How could I go through the list to get the node, and return the whole "skill" object to be looped later?

Thanks. :)

p.s: I can't do it with Java APIs

Answer (score 0):

From the architecture point of view it would be better to implement a regular interface (Iterable, Iterator or maybe one from a collection, which suits better) in the QueueList, which allows iterating over your collection.

Otherwise you could just manually iterate over your nodes using a plain old loop. Here is a possible implementation of a method from the QueueList class, which returns zero year skills of a given person:

```
public List<Skills> getSkillsWithoutExperience() {
    List<Skills> noSkillsList = new ArrayList();
    Node<Skills> node = skillsList.getLastNode();
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.getItem().getYears() <= 0) {
            noSkillsList.add(node.getItem());
        }
        node = node.getNextNode();
    }
    return noSkillsList;
}
```

P.S. method names in Java use camelCaseNotation, so they start from lower case letter :)